# Returning multiple subsets of data

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I am implementing a Silverlight project in which I have to access the database and fetch the results from a table using WCF. The source table contains more than million records.

I have no problems in fetching the records. But the thing is, I don't want to wait till it loops all the records. I want to return the subsets of the data so that the end user need not wait for a long time. Is it possible to send multiple subsets of the original data ?

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using WCF RIA [DomainDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707363%28v=vs.91%29.aspx). It has many advantages like paged datasets through paging, filtering, grouping.

The clear benefit using this control is only paged/filtered/grouped data being fetched by RIA services of your domain context over the channel. It contains simplistic configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. Why are you looping through all the records in the first place? You should really be using something like Entity Framework to act as your mapper, and turn your db schema into class objects. 
Then you could also use linq to control your own paging methods, using `skip` and `take`. 
You could also use various data pager controls which will handle the paging for you for you.

Basically the worst thing you could be doing is just manually iterating over records yourself and bringing everything back at once.